# How to show notification about bluetooth status everytime it changes in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I have made custom keyboard shortcut to toggle bluetooth using tlp and wished to know its status in the form of a notification, I was thinking of using notify-send command to do it but haven't figured out a way to know the status of bluetooth (whether it's on or off).

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: I am using Pop OS 20.04 (I thought i would get more hits on adding Ubuntu in the title), currently i have simply binded a shortcut to a simple script with: notify-send "$(bluetooth toggle)", but i'd like to have a bit of control on what message is notified depending on whether bluetooth is off or on.